# Using GWT's Pair in client code

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to use the class Pair from GWT:

`com.google.gwt.dev.util.Pair`

But I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Line 126: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.dev.util.Pair<L,R>; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

In MyModule.gwt.xml I inherit the module com.google.gwt.user.User:

`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />`

Which module do I need in order to use that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code under the package `com.google.gwt.dev` only runs in the JVM.

If you want to reuse `Pair`, you have to copy it to a client side or shared namespace. But in this case you have to use different imports.

If you want to reuse it with the same namespace, you have to create your own `.gwt.xml` file that includes the `com.google.gwt.dev` namespace, but it is not an easy task since you might need a lot of exceptions in order to avoid other classes in this namespace using any kind of java code making gwt compiler fail.

Comment: Thanks! can you give a link that explains this behavior? (Code under the package com.google.gwt.dev only runs in the JVM.)

Comment: Actually is just the contrary, code under packages covered by .gwt.xml modules can be used in client side: Hope this clarifies the question: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_Client.html#What_is_a_GWT_Module?